# Alpaca - Replace '★' with '*' on required field

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

Is there a way to replace the Star symbol with an asterisk on a 'required' field label on Alpaca? 
[image]

Here is the schema:

```
var Schema = {
    "title": "Lista controlli",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "Controllo Lavorazione",
        "properties": {
            ...
            "Nome": {
                "title": "Nome",
                "type": "string",
                "required": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with that using css like this:

```
.alpaca-icon-required::before {
    content: "*"
}
```

You could also change it's font-size because it will be kinda big.

Hope this works for you. I this isn't what you're looking for don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Thank you, that works pretty well. Just needed to add the main font family to get the right size of the *

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version, 1.5.24, the star preceding the field label has been replaced with the text '***(required)***' following the field label.